# Howto act as a syslog receiver?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I want to be a receiver of specific syslog logs. So collect all the syslog messages from one program and push these to the user.

Is there a way I can "subscribe" me at syslog for a unit's log messages?

Other than file watching or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was for rsyslog and can be done via the omuxsock module.
omuxsock == "output module unix socket"
which is part of rsyslog.
This module "writes" the logs to a unix socket, which needs to be created by the receiving program.
EDIT:
Here is an example for the receiving program:

```
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*
this program acts as a receiver for rsyslog messages.
Just create a .conf file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ with the
following content:

$ModLoad omuxsock
$Template MyForwardTemplate,"%PRI%|%TIMESTAMP%|%HOSTNAME%|%syslogtag%|%msg%"
$OMUxSockSocket /tmp/mysock
*.* :omuxsock:;MyForwardTemplate

*/

vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    vector<string> tokens;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char *mysocketpath = "/tmp/mysock";
    struct sockaddr_un namesock;
    char buffer[512] = { 0 };
    int fd;
    int ret;

    namesock.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(namesock.sun_path, (char *)mysocketpath, sizeof(namesock.sun_path));

    cerr << "creating the socket ..." << endl;
    fd = ::socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    cerr << "binding it to the socket path ..." << endl;
    ret = ::bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &namesock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    if(ret != 0) {
        cerr << "bind error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        ret = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    do {
        memset(buffer, 0, 512);
        ret = ::read(fd, buffer, 512);
        if(ret > 0) {
            string s = buffer;
            vector<string> v = split(buffer, '|');

            if(v.size() == 5)
                cerr << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ", " << v[3] << ", " << v[4] << endl;
            else {
                for(string s : v) {
                    cerr << s << ", ";
                }
                cerr << endl;
            }
        }
    } while(ret > 0);

exit:
    close(fd);
    unlink(mysocketpath);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: can you post an example please, i have configured rsyslog to send logs to a unix socket, but when i create the unix socket and listen to it. i cannot see any message.

Comment: Added a sample C++ source to my answer which worked for me.